# Automate way to have links of all documents copied into one library page?

Tags: search, library, hyperlink

Newbie here with newbie question. I have been tasked with making a departmental SharePoint site more usable. The complaint is nothing can be found.

All the content is heavily sub-foldered as different people took over control of the site.

I was wondering if a meta tag search function would uncover the content and make it more visible. This means tagging hundreds of files, but that is just donkey work.

The big issue from my perspective is to be able to copy links of all documents into one library which I would then use for the metatagging and searching.

So my questions:

1. would this approach work? And let me know if my background and
   desired outcome is not clear, and
2. Is there an automated scripted way that I can have hundreds of files
   in folder A be linked to a master directory library which will be my
   main search area?

Many thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by linked to master directory? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need documents to be found easily based on metadata.

Considering that requirement, the suggested approach would be to create a aContent Type based on Document with a Managed Metadata column.
Documents can then be tagged with terms from the term store, which in turn will be surfaced by the refiners in a Search page.

Regarding the tagging of multiple existing documents, PowerShell sounds like your best friend if you have someone with coding skills. You can create a script that iterates through the documents and based on folders or libraries applies a specific term.

Managed Metadata
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Search Refiners
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/11/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

PowerShell to update Managed Metadata
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/15/updating-sharepoint-managed-metadata-columns-with-powershell.aspx

I know that this solution is not matching the title of the question, but it does seem appropriate, more scalable and SharePointy than having a list of links.